# What is the result/effect of layers.__init__ in side a class without declaring them as variables?

Tags: python, pytorch

First to declear, I am not good at Python yet.

Below is a snippet of the original microsoft LoRA implementation.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

import math
from typing import Optional, List

class LoRALayer():
    def __init__(
        self, 
        r: int, 
        lora_alpha: int, 
        lora_dropout: float,
        merge_weights: bool,
    ):
        self.r = r
        self.lora_alpha = lora_alpha
        # Optional dropout
        if lora_dropout > 0.:
            self.lora_dropout = nn.Dropout(p=lora_dropout)
        else:
            self.lora_dropout = lambda x: x
        # Mark the weight as unmerged
        self.merged = False
        self.merge_weights = merge_weights


class Embedding(nn.Embedding, LoRALayer):
    # LoRA implemented in a dense layer
    def __init__(
        self,
        num_embeddings: int,
        embedding_dim: int,
        r: int = 0,
        lora_alpha: int = 1,
        merge_weights: bool = True,
        **kwargs
    ):
        nn.Embedding.__init__(self, num_embeddings, embedding_dim, **kwargs)
        LoRALayer.__init__(self, r=r, lora_alpha=lora_alpha, lora_dropout=0,
                            merge_weights=merge_weights)
        # Actual trainable parameters
        if r > 0:
            self.lora_A = nn.Parameter(self.weight.new_zeros((r, num_embeddings)))
            self.lora_B = nn.Parameter(self.weight.new_zeros((embedding_dim, r)))
            self.scaling = self.lora_alpha / self.r
            # Freezing the pre-trained weight matrix
            self.weight.requires_grad = False
        self.reset_parameters()

    def reset_parameters(self):
        nn.Embedding.reset_parameters(self)
        if hasattr(self, 'lora_A'):
            # initialize A the same way as the default for nn.Linear and B to zero
            nn.init.zeros_(self.lora_A)
            nn.init.normal_(self.lora_B)

    def train(self, mode: bool = True):
        nn.Embedding.train(self, mode)
        if mode:
            if self.merge_weights and self.merged:
                # Make sure that the weights are not merged
                if self.r > 0:
                    self.weight.data -= (self.lora_B @ self.lora_A).transpose(0, 1) * self.scaling
                self.merged = False
        else:
            if self.merge_weights and not self.merged:
                # Merge the weights and mark it
                if self.r > 0:
                    self.weight.data += (self.lora_B @ self.lora_A).transpose(0, 1) * self.scaling
                self.merged = True
        
    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor):
        if self.r > 0 and not self.merged:
            result = nn.Embedding.forward(self, x)
            after_A = F.embedding(
                x, self.lora_A.transpose(0, 1), self.padding_idx, self.max_norm,
                self.norm_type, self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse
            )
            result += (after_A @ self.lora_B.transpose(0, 1)) * self.scaling
            return result
        else:
            return nn.Embedding.forward(self, x)
```

I have 2 python questions here.

1. What is effect/result of nn.Embedding.**init** and LoRALayer.**init** in Embedding class without making them as variables? They are like this below.

```
        nn.Embedding.__init__(self, num_embeddings, embedding_dim, **kwargs)
        LoRALayer.__init__(self, r=r, lora_alpha=lora_alpha, lora_dropout=0,
                            merge_weights=merge_weights)
```

They are not like `embedding = nn.Embedding()` or `lora = LoRALayer()`. What do they do inside the Embedding class when they are not decleared as variables?

2. The LoRALayer class was never been used or called in Embedding class except `LoRALayer.__init__(self, r=r, lora_alpha=lora_alpha, lora_dropout=0, merge_weights=merge_weights)`

Then how does it work and why is it there?

Thank you for your kind explanations in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for first question - this code use python's syntax for inheritance, that mean `class Embedding` has two parents `nn.Embedding, LoRALayer`, calls `LoRALayer.__init__...` and `nn.Embedding.__init__...` run parents `__init__`
that's why there's no variables `embedding = nn.Embedding()` or `lora = LoRALayer()`

for second part of question - the `class LoRALayer` only has **init** method which will be call when create `class Embedding` and in this code is set initial value for fields, these fields you can use in `class Embedding`

for my opinion, it's not the best code to achieve the goal, but it's the way how it works